# Are there any implementations\prototypes of Erlang alike VM that could run not only on CPU but also on gpu?

Tags: erlang, gpu, distributed, distributed-computing, elixir

I was creating distributed systems in OOP languages using message passing libraries like MPI, ZepoMQ, RabbitMQ and so on. Now I found myself watching [some](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/self-heal-scalable-system) erlang [promotional material](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Message-Passing-Concurrency) and understood that lots of things we emulate in OOP languages like C++ and C# using libraries (1 000 000 socket connections per process, distributed messaging and distributed process monitoring visualization) was there in Erlang for many years now. And it seemed reasonable to get to know the language better. I found myself asking one last question: are there any implementations\prototypes of Erlang alike VM that could run/spawn some processes not only on CPU but also on GPU?

Because that would definitely make Erlang (and its more readable for my OOP background dialects like [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html)) language of choice for most future projects.

Comment: `Erlang` processes are not related to the operating system and especially with graphics.

Answer (score 1):

GPU is fast only with sequential memory access. I hardly imagine garbage collection on GPU RAM. GPU is NOT a cool and parallel CPU. It requires more effort to write to. So most probably there is no Erlang compiler for GPU.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's any implementation that can run Erlang processes on GPU but you can use two techniques to run computations on GPU under Erlang:

- use C library through NIFs (native implemented functions) - see http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html and an example of such an implementation: msantos/procket on Github (I'm sorry, I can't post the link due to low reputation :)
- use native OS process and communicate with it through erlang "port" - see http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/ports.html

The first one is faster and the later is safer (NIFs can crash the whole VM).

This is not specific to GPU coputations. Erlang is not well suited for high performance number crunching - it's better to do it in C and manipulate the results in Erlang anyway. The communication between the C and Erlang should be implemented in the one of the two described manners.